# Why does $((40-35)) turn into 5?

Tags: bash, shell, arithmetic

What kind of strange shell syntax is hidden behind `$((40-35))` and how come it calculates a value?

Example:

```
$> echo $((40-35))
5
```

Comment: Open `bash` manual page and search for `^ *Arithmetic Expansion`

Comment: In tcsh, it just gives "Illegal variable name."

Comment: Why do you think it is "strange"?  It's in the man page.  'man sh'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the `bash` man page:

> ```
>   ((expression))
>           The expression is evaluated according  to  the  rules  described
>           below  under ARITHMETIC EVALUATION.  If the value of the expres-
>           sion is non-zero, the return status is 0; otherwise  the  return
>           status is 1.  This is exactly equivalent to let "expression".
> ```

And further:

> ```
>   Arithmetic Expansion
>     Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression and
>     the substitution of the result.  The format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
>           $((expression))
> ```

Anything put into double parens becomes a math expression that `bash` will evaluate.

Answer (score 4):

This is [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04). It's supported in all POSIX shells (it didn't exist in the original Bourne shell). The syntax of arithmetic expression is mostly the same as in the C language.

You can use variables with or without a `$` in an arithmetic expression. Without a `$`, a variable stands as a variable, and can in particular be assigned to; for example `echo $((a=4)) $a` prints `4 4`. With a `$`, the shell performs a simple text expansion; for example `a=2+2; echo $(($a))` prints `4` whereas `a=2+2; echo $((a))` is an error (but prints 4 on some shells anyway).

The exact rules for deciding whether `$((` begins a command substitution (`$(command)` where the command happens to begin with an opening parenthesis) or an airthmetic expression (`$((expression))`) vary from shell to shell. If you want to perform a command substitution and the command begins with `(`, put a space to be safe: `$( (echo hello))` (such commands are rare, which is why the syntax could be added without any practical danger of confusion).